# HDFS Replication Muchover

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, cloudera

I used default configuration (3 replication) in our Cloudera cluster. But some directory got over replication. Much of table inside this database/directory created by hive query (CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ....)
How can it happen?

[image: one of overmuch replication directory]

After seeing some configuration, I see that max replication set to 512. If this problem caused by this?

[image]

Comment: Any chance a facetious developer might have inserted a `SET dfs.replication =10  ; ` clause just before the CTAS...?

Comment: I don't think so. This directory created by running query on hue. The user don't put any config on their HUE. Just run the query. And this problem only happen to this directory, while another directory replication is OK